# Unable to resolve plugin "doctrine"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I am using doctrine in my ZF project and when I run it I get the exception.

> Exception message: Unable to resolve plugin "doctrine"; no
>   corresponding plugin with that name

Comment: What error are you talking about? please add it to your question.

Comment: Exception message : Unable to resolve plugin "doctrine"; no corresponding plugin with that name
This is the exception message which I m getting